# visual studio 2012 puts a small number in the top left corner of my screen

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I am wondering if anyone else has had this issue with visual studio (or a VS extension because I have a few installed) and what is causing this? The number goes away when I close visual studio and I have not been able to figure our what is causing this. The number is overlayed on my desktop and not just visual studio. It covers all other windows I have open as well telling me it's set to be always on top.

Anyone else come across this issue or what is causing it?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: If you have extensions installed, try disabling them and check whether it is VS or one of extensions.

Comment: I've tried that but the problem is that the number only rarely shows up. Sometimes it takes weeks before it will suddenly make appearance. :(

Comment: Have you ever figured this out? I'm still running into it in my Visual Studio 2015 installation.

Comment: In VS 2015 I have had the same number ;) Look through task manager, nothing funny there. So just like SO I have restarted VS

Comment: This seems to be related to the number of notifications. You'll see the same number on the right hand side of the title bar.

Comment: I closed a solution and had the rectangle duplicated in the middle of the IDE workspace.  Closing Visual Studio always makes it disappear and it doesn't reappear right away when I reopen VS.  It is so small I don't notice what causes it to appear

Comment: Still no answer for this? It's still happening in VS 2017.

Comment: Visual Studio editor team member here. It's a CodeLens keytip (they are shown when you press Alt while the caret is inside C# method) somehow getting leaked. Are there any (even approximate) steps to reproduce this issue? That would greatly help us fix it. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I figured it out!

This has been bothering me for years. I finally just sat down and solved the problem. Basically, VS has this little known feature where you can navigate through code lens with just your keyboard. If you press Alt for a couple of seconds, you will see numbers just like the ones that appear at the top of your screen above your current method. To fix it, just long press Alt again and the number should go away. If you have many VS instances open you might have to go through them one by one.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have significant reputation to comment, but I am experiencing this both with VS2013 and VS2015 too. The only extension I have installed is Resharper.

My research shows that it is caused by the hover text / overlays from various components. The only way I have found to get rid of them is to close the Visual Studio IDE window responsible.