# What is this small grey box with a number appearing in Visual Studio's title bar?

Tags: visual-studio

Every now and again when I'm running Visual Studio, I get this mysterious grey box in the upper left-hand corner of my screen with a number in it.  It's always a different number, and the box is "always on top" and doesn't disappear until I completely exit out of Visual Studio.  I've searched high and low on Google and SO and can't find anything.

Does anyone have any idea what this is?

[image: screenshot of top-left corner of Visual Studio interface, with a number "7" in a grey box right next to the Visual Studio logo]

Comment: Could it be the notifications count that's normally in the top right corner?

Comment: I would suggest having a look at [this Stack Overflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27101609/6049581) and also this answer on the [Microsoft Forum](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-desktop/small-gray-box-in-upper-left-hand-corner/1f3c01ea-d12d-41b0-b9d7-954e675f75e0). It seems that your problem is related to the Dell Backup & Restore Manager.

Comment: Well, wouldn't we all be so shocked if some shovelware that came with your computer was causing problems. Maybe that's why ["Dell Backup and Recovery 1.8 is no longer shipped in Dell systems."](http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/SLN297423/dell-backup-and-recovery-18--overview-and-install) Do be sure to post an answer if you confirm Frits's suspicions.

Comment: Thanks for the responses.  I do not have Dell Backup & Recovery, and it doesn't correspond to the notifications that show in the top right as Andy suggested either.